# Using different package names for bindings and wsdl using the jaxws maven plugin

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, jax-ws-customization, jaxws-maven-plugin

We have a special requirement with our application: files generated **against the wsdl** should have **a given package name** and files **generated against xsd files** should have **another package name**.

There does not seem to have a way to customize this with the jaxws maven plugin. Here is our current configuration:

```
    <execution>
        <id>wsimport-finderpro</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/xml-resources/web-service-references/B2T_DataModel.asmx/xsd</bindingDirectory>
            <bindingFiles>
                <bindingFile>ServerResponse_login.xsd</bindingFile>
                <bindingFile>OpenDirectAccessSession.xsd</bindingFile>
            </bindingFiles>
            <!--wsdls file directory -->
            <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/xml-resources/web-service-references/B2T_DataModel.asmx/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
            <!-- which wsdl file -->
            <wsdlFiles>
                <wsdlFile>B2T_DataModel.asmx.wsdl</wsdlFile>
            </wsdlFiles>
            <!-- Keep generated files -->
            <keep>true</keep>
            <!-- Package name -->
            <packageName>com.mycompany.world.worldlink.finderpro.ws</packageName>
            <!-- generated source files destination-->
            <sourceDestDir>target/generated-code/src</sourceDestDir>
            <staleFile>target/jaxws/fp/.staleFlag</staleFile>
            <target>2.1</target>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```

Can anyone please advise?

**edit 1**: I came up with the following code:

```
            <execution>
                <id>wsimport-finderpro-01</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/xml-resources/web-service-references/B2T_DataModel.asmx/xsd</bindingDirectory>
                    <bindingFiles>
                        <bindingFile>OpenDirectAccessSession.xsd</bindingFile>
                    </bindingFiles>
                    <!--wsdls file directory -->
                    <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/xml-resources/web-service-references/B2T_DataModel.asmx/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                    <!-- which wsdl file -->
                    <wsdlFiles>
                        <wsdlFile>B2T_DataModel.asmx.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    </wsdlFiles>
                    <!-- Keep generated files -->
                    <keep>true</keep>
                    <!-- Package name -->
                    <packageName>com.ids.world.worldlink.finderpro.xmlstubs</packageName>
                    <!-- generated source files destination-->
                    <sourceDestDir>target/generated-code/src</sourceDestDir>
                    <staleFile>target/jaxws/fp-01/.staleFlag</staleFile>
                    <target>2.1</target>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>wsimport-finderpro-02</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/xml-resources/web-service-references/B2T_DataModel.asmx/xsd</bindingDirectory>
                    <bindingFiles>
                        <bindingFile>GetAllMyEntityQuotes.xsd</bindingFile>
                    </bindingFiles>
                    <!--wsdls file directory -->
                    <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/xml-resources/web-service-references/B2T_DataModel.asmx/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                    <!-- which wsdl file -->
                    <wsdlFiles>
                        <wsdlFile>B2T_DataModel.asmx.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    </wsdlFiles>
                    <!-- Keep generated files -->
                    <keep>true</keep>
                    <!-- Package name -->
                    <packageName>com.ids.world.worldlink.finderpro.xmlstubs.allMyEntityQuotes</packageName>
                    <!-- generated source files destination-->
                    <sourceDestDir>target/generated-code/src</sourceDestDir>
                    <staleFile>target/jaxws/fp-02/.staleFlag</staleFile>
                    <target>2.1</target>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
```

The issue is that I noticed that many classes are regenerated several times (here x2) and I end up with same classes in different packages.

**How can I ensure that classes generated for the wsdl are generated once and classes for the xsd are generated and placed in their respective package**?

Comment: Were you able to find a resolution to this issue?